# Is it necessary to rebuild index after changing column default value?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Is is necessary to drop and re-create an index involving a particular column when that column is altered so that the default value is changed? My column looks like `SubNum varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` and I want to change it to `SubNum varchar(8) NOT NULL`. My related indexes looks like:

```
KEY `Docs1` (`First`,`SubNum`,`DocNum`),
KEY `Docs2` (`SubNum`,`DocNum`),
```

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.49 and the table is `MyIsam`.

Comment: `not null default null` is not a valid setting, to start with.

Comment: Why do you think you need to re-create the index? changing the default value of a field does not change any value for existing fields.

Comment: @Luuk I've come across information that says that indexes need to be rebuilt after column data type change (and others that say not necessary) but I would just like to know if this is something that needs to be done. I would have assumed not, but thought it was worth asking the question.

Comment: @GMB sorry I meant to just drop the `default ''`

Comment: The `DEFAULT ''` has not much to do with the datatype, which is `VARCHAR(8)`. If you change the `8` then you need to rebuild the index.

Comment: But `''` is the default for `DEFAULT` on strings?  So what change are you expecting??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the default value of a column does not change it's data-type. Given that the column was not-null before the change, this change does not affect any existing data - it just changes the default for the next row inserted. Since the currently stored data does not change, there's no need to rebuild the index.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reindex it after altering the table, internally it will create a new table and index it too.